# Service that outputs your ip and geo location and other ip related info in the commandline like wtfismyip.com?

Tags: terminal, console, geolocation, ip

I've been using wtfismyip.com to get info about my ip by doing

**curl wtfismyip.com/json**

It outputs all the info to the terminal in a nice json format. Is there another service like this for outputting to the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

**curl http://api.db-ip.com/v2/free/self**

This outputs your IP info in a JSON format, you can also specify a field name in order to get a text response (ie. http://api.db-ip.com/v2/free/self/countryCode)